# how jenkins job console output works?

Tags: ajax, jenkins

I am thinking to integrate console outputting technology of jenkins job in one my application. We see that jenkins jobs continuously prints the command output in console with minimum buffer and no page refresh. Can anyone detail how its achieved in jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it has an ajax request which asks for chunks of log every second. More info can be found [here](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/How-to-implement-progressiveHtml-kind-of-an-approach-td4649823.html). Links to files mentioned in the post; [LargeText](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/LargeText.java), [console.jelly](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/hudson/model/Run/console.jelly), [progressiveTest.jelly](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/lib/hudson/progressiveText.jelly).